Exogeneity of instruments for 2SLS with fixed effects
Consider a model of the form $Y_{it} = X_{it} \beta + c_i + u_{it}$ where $X_{it}$ is endogenous. From Wooldridge's panel data book, if I have an instrument $Z_{it}$ that is strictly exogenous $E(Z_{it}u_{is}) = 0$ for all $t,s$, then I can obtain consistent estimates by demeaning the variables in the original model and running pooled 2SLS with these instrument (of course assuming the instrument is correlated with endogenous $X_{it}$)
But many papers include fixed effects $c_i$ but only consider instruments that are contemporaneously uncorrelated with the leftover error term: $E(Z_{it}u_{it}) = 0$ for all $t$. Why is this the case? Don't we need strict exogeneity of instruments for consistency if we first demean the variables (to remove $c_i$) then estimate with pooled 2SLS?
